# OpenGL pink color in release mode

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opengl, game-engine

OpenGL shows empty texture colored as **white** in debug mode and colored as **pink** in release mode, key different only in Runtime Library (Release: MT, Debug: MTd).

IDE: Visual Studio 2013 (Update 5)

Question - why it's happens and how to fix?

Release: [image: img]

Debug: [image: img]

Comment: Maybe there is some type of initialization bug in your code.

Comment: @drescherjm I not exclude hand-made mistake, but real different in two builds only in MT / MTd (optimization, checks, preprocessor is same), but effect as you can see in the pictures, if it's initialization bug - must happens in any runtime library, right?

Comment: In debug mode memory is filled with patterns 0xcc for stack variables. 0xcd for heap. This does not happen in release.

Comment: @drescherjm You are right! Thanks you for fast answer & useful tip. If you wish - create 'answer message' and i will select it's as final.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're most likely reading from uninitialized memory. To aid debugging this kind of issue, in *debug* builds, the runtime library (and depending on compiler toolchain also the compiler) insert code, that fill all memory allocations with *canary value* patterns. These patterns may either show up in reads that are out-of-bounds or to uninitialized memory. Similarly sanity checking code tests the integrity patterns to test for out-of-bounds writes.

Since on currently widespread computer architectures memory protection only works at a certain granularity, namely the *page size*, which in most cases is 4096 bytes¹, to detect memory corruption those canary values are used.

Anyway, the reason you're seeing different values in *debug* vs. *release* builds is, that memory is actually initialized differently, for each case, and that shows up. **What's important for you is, that because a difference shows up, your code does something wrong, i.e. you have a bug that must be fixed!**

If you were building this for Linux my recommendation would be to run your program through the [*Valgrind memory debugger*](http://valgrind.org/). Valgrind is a tool that's specifically designed for debugging these kinds of errors. It roughly works by running your code through an emulated CPU, tracking each and every single memory allocation and acces, telling you down to the source code line, where illegal accesses happen.

There's a SO Q&A on Valgrind substitutes for Windows development: [Is there a good Valgrind substitute for Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/413477/is-there-a-good-valgrind-substitute-for-windows)

---

1: huge pages (typically 2MiB) and gigapages (typically 1GiB) are often available as well, but unless you request those explicitly, it's just the standard page size.